# How to send bulk personalized email using mailgun & nodejs

Tags: node.js, email, mailgun

The requirement is to send personalized email to more than 50k users, the recipient should be addressed by their names like below:

**Subject : Hello [name]**

**Message : How are you [name] ? and some other text**

I'm currently looping through the entire user collection to send the emails one at a time using **Mailgun** API and that's making 50k requests to mailgun server.

Mailgun API does not allow multiple subject or body, what's the best approach to solving this problem? 
I don't mind switching from mailgun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [mailing lists](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-mailinglists.html) feature:

> A mailing list is a group of members (recipients) which itself has an email address, like developers@mailgun.net. This address becomes an ID for this mailing list.

Then you can add members to this list, and assign every member a `name` property and any other fields you'd like. After that [recipient variables](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#batch-sending) can be used to replace placeholders like `%recipient.name%` with a name of every contact automatically.

This feature is described in [batch sending](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#batch-sending) section of their docs, as well as another option that does not require to create a mailing list.